# Do I need to manually deal with all this code if I use Glew?

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I'm following this tutorial at Open.gl
This page specifically (at the bottom) - http://open.gl/context
And it says that I have to use this code in my program (not really sure why...)

```
// Specify prototype of function
typedef void (*GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);

// Load address of function and assign it to a function pointer
GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
// or Linux:
GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS)glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte *) "glGenBuffers");
// or OSX:
GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS)NSGLGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");

// Call function as normal
Gluint buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
```

But then he says something about Glew fixing this 'problem' (not sure what that problem is)
but do I need the code above if I install Glew or does it do it for me?

Also there doesn't seem to be a function there that 'checks?' windows, just Linux and OSX...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL needs function pointers for most of its *modern* functions. The issue is however that the OpenGL libraries are created by many different driver manufacturers so the locations of these functions aren't always known. Therefore you have to query the location of each of those functions in OpenGL and store them in a function pointer. That is what the code you posted does: query the location of those function pointers and store them for later use.

However, when you have thousands of functions this becomes quite a cumbersome process to do. GLEW does **exactly** this for you. It retrieves all the function pointers for you so you don't have to care about all the function pointers and you can simply just use them in your application. In the example posted at open.gl he showed 3 different ways of retrieving those pointers (for windows, linux and mac).

The only thing you have to care about is the call to `glewInit()` (after you've created your OpenGL context) and you can use all of OpenGL's functions. The snippet you posted is simply how GLEW operates under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem here is that you need to use 3 different libraries to use opengl extensions (like ARB functions): WGL, glX and NSGL.

So, instead of filling your code with `#ifdef WIN32` and similar macros, you can just use `glewGetExtension` function that works cross-platform. This way, you can check which extensions are supported by your GPU, get the function pointer and use them accordingly.

http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html

edit: there isn't a code that checks OS, right. you should add macros for that, such as `#ifdef WIN32`